# I purchased vector clip art, it has multiple colors in the art, but none of the colors are listed in swatches

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cmyk, swatches

...and I need to convert to CMYK. How do I get the list of colors to convert? "Recolor artwork" and convert to CMYK under edit both do not work. Convert was greyed out and unavailable. Help!

Comment: in what program?

Answer (score 1):

- Make certain the Document Color Mode is set to CMYK as well before doing any of this (`File > Document Color Mode > CMYK color`)

Select all....

Click the `Create Color Group` button at the bottom of the **Swatch Panel**

[image]

In the pop up dialog for the color group, make certain `Convert Process to Global` is checked.

[image]

You will then have swatches for all colors (but not for gradients or patterns).

To edit one of the colors, just double click the swatch and you can adjust the sliders. Ticking the `Preview` option will allow you to see color change in the artwork where that swatch is used.

- I don't know why Convert to CMYK is not available to you. You've not posted any real details.
- `Recolor Artwork` should also work fine. Again, you've left out details.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to convert to CMYK? You could view them in "recolor artwork" and see the values but you can also sample the colors and add them to your swatch. Or you just can change the document color mode to CMYK under the edit menu.